# How can I take psql dump of one particular table and all it's dependencies?

Tags: sql, postgresql, pg-dump

I have a database with an accounts table( 3 accounts in it) and a couple of other tables which is having an account table Account_ID as a foreign key. Now my query is, I want to take a dump of 1st account in the accounts table and all its related tables (like the tables and rows init is having 1st account  account_id as a foreign key).

What I tried is, manually mentioning all table names in the command :
`pg_dump --column-inserts -a -t zones_seq -t interway -t table_3 ... > /tmp/zones_seq.sql` But it didn't work. Any help please..

Comment: You can't dump specific rows with `pg_dump`.

Comment: Thanks, Adrian for your reply. If it not possible with pg_dump, do we have any alternate way to achieve my target? (Like any client tool etc..)

Comment: Your `pg_dump` command shows you only wanting to dump the data, but your description implies you want the table definitions also. Can you be more specific about that as an update to your question. A quick idea would be to do a `CREATE TABLE accts_table_1 AS select * from accts_table where id =1` and repeat for the other tables, then `pg_dump` those tables.